# Which twin produces more widgets?

Tags: special-relativity, spacetime, reference-frames, time-dilation, observers

Two twins are identical in every way, including their [widget](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Widget_(economics)) production.

One twin goes on a long space trip at near the speed of light to produce widgets during the trip.

When space-twin returns he has aged less than earth-twin. But, who produced more widgets?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is as straightforward as it seems at first glance. If the twin's ability to produce widgets is the same then the widget, $w$, is effectively just a unit of time related to the second by some constant of proportionality $w = at$, where the constant $a$ is the same for both twins. So the accelerating twin produces fewer widgets than the twin who remains on Earth.

Were you thinking there should be more to it than that?

Comment: I suspected as much, but wasn't sure. Does NASA know that space travel is less productive?

Comment: I imagine NASA are well aware of the implications, but since they currently cannot accelerate a spacecraft to more than a tiny fraction of the speed of light I doubt they are losing any sleep over it :-)